# Generate functions at compile time

Tags: c++11

I have an image. Every pixel contains information about RGB intensity. Now I want to sum intenity these channels, but I also want to choose which channels intensity to sum. Straightforwad implementation of this would look like this:

```
int intensity(const unsiged char* pixel, bool red, bool green, bool blue){
    return 0 + (red ? pixel[0] : 0) + (green ? pixel[1] : 0) + (blue ? pixel[2] : 0);
}
```

Because I will call this function for every pixel in image I want to discard all conditions If I can. So I guess I have to have a function for every case:

```
std::function<int(const unsigned char* pixel)> generateIntensityAccumulator(
    const bool& accumulateRChannel,
    const bool& accumulateGChannel,
    const bool& accumulateBChannel)
    {
    if (accumulateRChannel && accumulateGChannel && accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[0]) + static_cast<int>(pixel[1]) + static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
            };
        }

        if (!accumulateRChannel && accumulateGChannel && accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[1]) + static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
            };
        }

        if (!accumulateRChannel && !accumulateGChannel && accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
            };
        }

        if (!accumulateRChannel && !accumulateGChannel && !accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return 0;
            };
        }

        if (accumulateRChannel && !accumulateGChannel && !accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[0]);
            };
        }

        if (!accumulateRChannel && accumulateGChannel && !accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[1]);
            };
        }

        if (accumulateRChannel && !accumulateGChannel && accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[0]) + static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
            };
        }

        if (accumulateRChannel && accumulateGChannel && !accumulateBChannel){
            return [](const unsigned char* pixel){
                return static_cast<int>(pixel[0]) + static_cast<int>(pixel[1]);
            };
        }
    }
```

Now I can use this generator before entering image loop and use function without any conditions:

```
...

auto accumulator = generateIntensityAccumulator(true, false, true);

for(auto pixel : pixels){
auto intensity = accumulator(pixel);
}

...
```

But it is a lot of writting for such simple task and I have a feeling that there is a better way to accomplish this: for example make compiler to do a dirty work for me and generate all above cases. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you actually performance-tested the above?  I'm surprised that moving simple boolean tests outside the loop should matter so much, since processors typically optimize branches by assuming "same result as last time"...

Comment: I admit I haven't - I just assumed that dicarding conditions will produce better result in performance. I read about branch preditiction (http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/) and I guess it will work in my case. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I could be wrong... I'd just consider running a performance test before doing anything too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `std::function` like this will cost you dear, because you dont let a chance for the compiler to optimize by inlining what it can.

What you are trying to do is a good job for templates. And since you use integral numbers, the expression itself may be optimized away, sparing you the need to write a specialization of each version. Look at this example :

```
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

template <bool AccumulateR, bool AccumulateG, bool AccumulateB>
inline int accumulate(const unsigned char *pixel) {
  static constexpr int enableR = static_cast<int>(AccumulateR);
  static constexpr int enableG = static_cast<int>(AccumulateG);
  static constexpr int enableB = static_cast<int>(AccumulateB);
  return enableR * static_cast<int>(pixel[0]) +
         enableG * static_cast<int>(pixel[1]) +
         enableB * static_cast<int>(pixel[2]);
}

int main(void) {
  std::vector<std::array<unsigned char, 3>> pixels(
      1e7, std::array<unsigned char, 3>{0, 0, 0});

  // Fill up with randomness
  std::random_device rd;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned char> dist(0, 255);
  for (auto &pixel : pixels) {
    pixel[0] = dist(rd);
    pixel[1] = dist(rd);
    pixel[2] = dist(rd);
  }

  // Measure perf
  using namespace std::chrono;

  auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  int sum1 = 0;
  for (auto const &pixel : pixels)
    sum1 += accumulate<true, true, true>(pixel.data());
  auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  int sum2 = 0;
  for (auto const &pixel : pixels)
    sum2 += accumulate<false, true, false>(pixel.data());
  auto t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "Sum 1 " << sum1 << " in "
            << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << "ms\n";
  std::cout << "Sum 2 " << sum2 << " in "
            << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3 - t2).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

Compiled with **Clang 3.9** with `-O2`, yields this result on my CPU:

```
Sum 1 -470682949 in 7ms
Sum 2 1275037960 in 2ms
```

Please notice the fact that we have an overflow here, you may need to use something bigger than an `int`. A `uint64_t` might do. If you inspect assembly code, you will see that the two versions of the function are inlined and optimized differently.

Answer (score 1):

First things first.  Don't write a `std::function` that takes a single `pixel`; write one that takes a contiguous range of `pixel`s (a scanline of pixels).

Second, you want to write a `template` version of `intensity`:

```
template<bool red, bool green, bool blue>
int intensity(const unsiged char* pixel){
  return (red ? pixel[0] : 0) + (green ? pixel[1] : 0) + (blue ? pixel[2] : 0);
}
```

pretty simple, eh?  That will optimize down to your hand-crafted version.

```
template<std::size_t index>
int intensity(const unsiged char* pixel){
  return intensity< index&1, index&2, index&4 >(pixel);
}
```

this one maps from the bits of `index` to which of the `intensity<bool, bool, bool>` to call.  Now for the scanline version:

```
template<std::size_t index, std::size_t pixel_stride=3>
int sum_intensity(const unsiged char* pixel, std::size_t count){
  int value = 0;
  while(count--) {
    value += intensity<index>(pixel);
    pixel += pixel_stride;
  }
  return value;
}
```

We can now generate our scanline intensity calculator:

```
int(*)( const unsigned char* pel, std::size_t pixels )
scanline_intensity(bool red, bool green, bool blue) {
  static const auto table[] = {
    sum_intensity<0b000>, sum_intensity<0b001>,
              sum_intensity<0b010>, sum_intensity<0b011>,
    sum_intensity<0b100>, sum_intensity<0b101>,
              sum_intensity<0b110>, sum_intensity<0b111>,
  };
  std::size_t index = red + green*2 + blue*4;
  return sum_intensity[index];
}
```

and done.

These techniques can be made generic, but you don't need the generic ones.

If your pixel stride is not 3 (say there is an alpha channel), `sum_intensity` needs to be passed it (as a template parameter ideally).